# Change device name in /sys/class

Tags: linux, sysfs, device-tree

I would like to know if there is a way to rename device under sysfs?

For example, I have a class regulator with severals devices under it

```
# ls /sys/class/regulator/
regulator.0   regulator.11  regulator.3   regulator.6   regulator.9
regulator.1   regulator.12  regulator.4   regulator.7
regulator.10  regulator.2   regulator.5   regulator.8
```

Each of this regulator have a name

```
# cat /sys/class/regulator/regulator.8/name
VCC_3V3
# cat /sys/class/regulator/regulator.9/name
VCC_2V5
```

I would like to know if it's possible to rename regulator.8 to VCC_3V3 for example ?

***Edit :*** I precise that I want to rename the device in sysfs and not have a symlink to it under `/dev/<device_class>/<device_name>` as I could export it with udev rules